# RSpec equality matcher failing for serializer test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rspec, active-model-serializers

I am writing a test for one of my Active Model Serializers to make sure that the JSON output is what I expect. However, I cannot figure out why RSpec is parsing my 'expected' output to leave out my array of testjobs, and I do not understand why I cannot get 'expected' and 'got' outputs to equal each other. At one point, I even copy-pasted the 'got' result to my 'expected' input and still received a failure message that the two strings were not equal. However, when I compared those two strings in REPL using **==**, the output was **true**. How do I resolve these issues to get an effective test?

```
RSpec Error:

Failures:

  1) TestrunSerializer creates special JSON for the API
     Failure/Error: expect(serializer.to_json).to eq('{"testrun":{"id":1,"run_at":null,"started_at":null,"state":"pending","completed_at":null,"testjobs":[{"id":2,"active":false,"testchunk_id":2,"testrun_id":1,"testchunk_name":"flair","testchunk":{"id":15,"name":"flair"}}],"branch":{"id":1,"name":"dev","repository":{"id":321,"url":"fakeurl.com"}}}}')

       expected: "{\"testrun\":{\"id\":1,\"run_at\":null,\"started_at\":null,\"state\":\"pending\",\"completed_at\":nu...r\"}}],\"branch\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"dev\",\"repository\":{\"id\":321,\"url\":\"fakeurl.com\"}}}}"
            got: "{\"testrun\":{\"id\":1,\"run_at\":null,\"started_at\":null,\"state\":\"pending\",\"completed_at\":nu...s\":[],\"branch\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"dev\",\"repository\":{\"id\":321,\"url\":\"fakeurl.com\"}}}}"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/serializers/testrun_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.79448 seconds (files took 5.63 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/serializers/testrun_spec.rb:8 # TestrunSerializer creates special JSON for the API
```

Here is the RSpec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe TestrunSerializer, type: :serializer do
  let(:repo)      { Repository.create(id: 321, url: "fakeurl.com") }
  let(:branch)    { Branch.create(id: 1,name: "dev", repository_id: repo.id) }
  let(:testchunk) { Testchunk.create(id: 15, name: "flair") }

  it "creates special JSON for the API" do
    serializer = TestrunSerializer.new Testrun.new("id":1, name: "name", "run_at": nil, state: "pending", branch_id: branch.id)
    testjob = Testjob.create(id: 8, active: false, testchunk_id: testchunk.id, testrun_id: 1)
    expect(serializer.to_json).to eq('{"testrun":{"id":1,"run_at":null,"started_at":null,"state":"pending","completed_at":null,"testjobs":[{"id":2,"active":false,"testchunk_id":2,"testrun_id":1,"testchunk_name":"flair","testchunk":{"id":15,"name":"flair"}}],"branch":{"id":1,"name":"dev","repository":{"id":321,"url":"fakeurl.com"}}}}')
  end
end
```

Here is the actual serializer:

```
class TestrunSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :run_at, :started_at, :state, :completed_at, :testjobs
  has_many :testjobs
  has_one :branch
end
```

Technologies used: Rails 5.1, RSpec 3.6, Ruby 2.4

Comment: The strings are not equal. I can't see exactly why, because they are truncated. But a difference is still visible: `"completed_at\":nu...r\"` vs `\"completed_at\":nu...s\":[]` --- I suggest you find out what the actual difference is!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason why your test didn't pass is trivial: inside the `it` block, you assigned the `Testrun id (1)` while creating the `Testjob` record, but the `Testrun` record does not exist.

`SomeActiveRecord.new()` will not create any actual record until you invoke `save()` on it, or you can just invoke `SomeActiveRecord.create` for that.

```
some_active_record = SomeActiveRecord.new(...)
some_active_record.save

# or
some_active_record = SomeActiveRecord.create(...)
```

So the final solution may look something like:

```
it "creates special JSON for the API" do
  testrun = Testrun.create(id: 1, name: "name", run_at: nil, state: "pending", branch_id: branch.id)
  serializer = TestrunSerializer.new(testrun)
  testjob = Testjob.create(id: 8, active: false, testchunk_id: testchunk.id, testrun_id: testrun.id)
  expect(serializer.to_json).to eq('{"testrun":{"id":1,"run_at":null,"started_at":null,"state":"pending","completed_at":null,"testjobs":[{"id":2,"active":false,"testchunk_id":2,"testrun_id":1,"testchunk_name":"flair","testchunk":{"id":15,"name":"flair"}}],"branch":{"id":1,"name":"dev","repository":{"id":321,"url":"fakeurl.com"}}}}')
end
```

---

#### Improvement Scope:

Please have a look at the tests for `:json` adapter in the `active_model_serializers` repo: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/test/action_controller/json/include_test.rb.

You can easily convert the tests to suite with `rspec`.

If you want to test the json output, then you should put the tests under `controller` or `request` specs; rather than in serializers. Because rendering json is the responsibility of the adapter; serializers merely feed the adapter with all the attributes and associations defined in them.

Comment: The object does not have to be committed to the database in order to serialize it. This is a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `testjobs` are not matching

```
completed_at\":nu...r\"}}],\"branch\"
```

vs

```
completed_at\":nu...s\":[],
```

You should set up your specs so the `testjobs` are returned as well.

Please note that the diff string is `cut` in the middle - this is one of the most annoying part of eq matcher when used with strings.

Edit: You may wont to switch to comparing arrays/hashes instead of strings to get better diffs. `expect(serializer).to eq {testrun: "..."}` (Drop `to_json` in your assertions)

Comment: I did notice that. It's almost as if RSpec is auto-truncating the string wherever I put `testjobs: []`. Why would it do that? I suspect that may have something to do with why the strings are getting warped, but I don't understand how or why RSpec is doing that.

Comment: It's just an issue with long strings. Switch to comparing hashes/arrays for better diffs (check my updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but WILL let you answer your question. Add this to `spec_helper.rb` and the results will no longer be center-truncated, so there is no mystery chunk missing in the middle.

```
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.max_formatted_output_length = nil
  end
```

You can also use an int like `1000` or `5000` instead of `nil` (unlimited length) if you get megabyte-long messages you don't want to see.

Answer (score -1):

Working solution:
I added the line 
`serializer.testjobs << testjob`
to explicitly associate the testjob with the object, and the test now passes.

Comment: sorry. such kind of monkey patching should be avoided. please have a look at my answer for elaboration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46294066/1977104